# design of event dispatcher

Tags: c++, design-patterns

there is a large c++ project that receives data from outside and after small processing, new data are sent to client code (within the app). now all the client code implements lots of interfaces (e.g. IOnConcreteDataReceived) and pointers to these interfaces are set to the part that receives data from outside.

Event dispatcher looks like a good choice for code decoupling. 
I would like to get the following code:

```
// dispatcher global access
IEventDispatcher & getEventDispatcher();
//producer:
ConcreteDataType data{values};
getEventDispatcher().fireEvent<ConcreteDataTypeEvent>(data);

//consumer:
getEventDispatcher().subscribe<ConcreteDataTypeEvent>([](const ConcreteDataType & data){ processData(data);});
```

As far as in most cases the data types are different the simplest solution that comes to mind is to use data types as event types:

```
//producer:
ConcreteDataType data{values};
getEventDispatcher().fireEvent<ConcreteDataType>(data);

//consumer:
getEventDispatcher().subscribe<ConcreteDataType>([](const ConcreteDataType & data){ processData(data);});
```

[the implementation is simple](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/X9oyTlgOtvf41AJs)

The only thing that i do not like about this variant is the usage of data types as event types. It does not look intuitive

Separation of event types from data types leads to more complicated code. there should be an association between event types and data types, possibly in a central place.

The question: Is the purity of design (separated event types and data types) worth additional efforts or usage data types as event types is not as bad as i think of it? 
How to implement compile-time checks for event type - data type association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace notstd {
  template<class T> struct tag_t{constexpr tag_t(){} using type=T;};
  template<class T> constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
  template<class Tag> using type=typename Tag::type;
}
```

this lets us manipulate types as values.  This is useful, because functions operate on values, and functions have ADL.

```
namespace dispatch_events {
  template<class T>
  constexpr notstd::tag_t<T> data_type_mapping( notstd::tag_t<T> ) { return {}; }

  template<class E>
  using data_type = notstd::type<decltype(data_type_mapping(notstd::tag<E>))>;
}
```

now, `dispatch_events::data_type<E>` is the type of the data used by event `E`.  By default, it is just `E`.

If you want to create an event with a different data type, create an event type like this:

```
namespace somewhere {
  struct some_data { int x = 0; };
}

namespace anywhere {
  struct event_bob {};

  constexpr notstd::tag_t<somewhere::some_data>
  data_type_mapping( notstd::tag_t<event_bob> ) { return {}; }
}
```

now, `dispatch_events::data_type< anywhere::event_bob >` is `somewhere::some_data`.

You get easy event<->data correspondence for the common case, and the ability to have the same data on multiple events without having a central registry anywhere.  Anyone mapping the event type to data type must have the event type in view; for this to work, they must also have the `data_type_mapping` function (and hence, the data type) as well.

Simply place the `data_type_mapping` function in the namespace of the event type, and all is good.

This also permits an event type to map to a primitive type, like `int`, or a type you do not own, like `std::shared_ptr<bob>`.

In case you are wondering how this works, it works because template evaluation looks up in the template declaration context and using ADL (argument dependent lookup).  ADL of `data_type_mapping` finds the non-template overload, and that is then preferred over the template overload in `dispatch_events` namespace.  ADL examines the arguments, and the template arguments of the arguments, to find namespaces to search for possible candidate overloads.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Based on your idea i decided to simplify it a bit: `template <class TEvent> struct EventDataMap { using TData = void; };` And in the client code : `class MyEvent{}; template <> struct EventDataMap<MyEvent> { using TData = AssociatedDataType; };` i do not see any disadvatages of this simple solution in comparison with yours. but maybe i missed something. working code: [link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UF5eAW3gAXhDQVaU)

Comment: @alex you are forced to write that specialization in the same namespace regardless of which namespace the event is in; I find that awkward.  Try the case of one namespace for event dispatching, and a different one contains the event type; you end up leaving the event type namespace, opening the dispatch namespace, specializing, closing the dispatch namespace, and returning to event type namespace, in the middle of a header file (as you should do that trait ASAP).  As an aside, you probably want to add a second `class=void` parameter to permit using logic based dispatch for your solution.

Comment: Thanks. now i understood the necessity of functions and your note about ADL